# Getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found while calling Mock Services

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, soapui

I am trying to call mock services which are running in SOAP UI. When i have done the same in my local machine and its working fine without any issues.

```
<p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.</p>
```

Application deployed in Linux server is x.x.x.10.

and mock services are running on SOAP UI and machine host name is DXXXX221.

and calling mock services like same as below:

```
Client Call end point:  http://DXXXX221:9090/ // Mock Services endpoint
```

Can anyone please suggest how to call mock services which are running in another system soap ui.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is package your project, including your mock services, as a WAR and deploy it to a servlet container such as Tomcat. Just right-click on your project and select "Deploy as WAR" which will give you a standard WAR file. Your mock services will be exposed as normal endpoints.

See [Deploying Mock Services as WAR Files](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/deploying-mock-services-as-war-files.html) for more details.

Comment: I exported as jar and deployed in tomcat then how i can check whether able to accessing or not? Thanks @craigcaulfield

Comment: Check out https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/deploying-mock-services-as-war-files.html. This shows how to export the WAR file and then then how to call it once it's deployed to Tomcat.